# Akka remoting with multiple clients?

Tags: scala, akka

I am developing an application to run as a command line tool, and I am using Scala/Akka. I would like for this command line tool to use a client/server architecture. When the first instance of this tool is launched, it launches an instance of a server in the background that actually does all of the processing. If a user then opens multiple terminal windows and launches more instances of this app, it will connect to the existing server rather than launch a new one. Basically I need multiple clients talking to a single server. Can this be accomplished with Akka's remoting, or do I need to run a more classic client/server architecture with a message broker in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done with Akka remoting.

You'll want to configure the "server" `ActorSystem` with a well-known port.  Then use `system.actorFor` in the clients to get an `ActorRef` to an actor running on the server.

Make sure the hostname that you use in the config is the same hostname that you use in the path that you use in `actorFor`.